# A white line appeared above my header and it won't go away

Tags: header, whitespace

On my wordpress site, i played a little bit with the header and IDK for what reason, this white dash/line appeared above my header (the one i marked with purple arrows). It is bugging me for a while and I decided to ask you guys if anyone would have any advice.
[Website white dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUdy.png)

Reverting it doesn't work, i have checked all margins, there are none whatsoever.